# when I doing Performance testing in Jmeter adding 1 user I got below sample result

Tags: java

```
Thread Name:Learner 1-1
Sample Start:2022-05-07 18:52:03 IST
Load time:151
Connect Time:89
Latency:151
Size in bytes:468
Sent bytes:916
Headers size in bytes:463
Body size in bytes:5
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):
Response code:405
Response message:


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

Comment: So what is your question? You present some (badly formatted) facts, but don't ask a question ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error you sent out, the code of this error is 405, so the biggest possibility is that your request was not approved by the server, because I don't know how you tested it, but I am good at redis, and I guess that your login token is invalid, so you can't receive the request normally. Of course, this is just my guess, and I hope it will help you.